# Assign column name as class name telerik grid mvc

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

i have a telerik grid in my view and i want to assign the column name as the class attribute

```
 .Columns(columns =>
        {

            columns.Bound(o => o.xyz).Width(70).Groupable(false).Title("Reply Status").HtmlAttributes(new { @class=xyz});      
                            ------^                                                                    -------------^                                         
        })
```

is that possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure you are strongly binding the view with the model

Next you can try

```
.Columns(columns =>
      {    
        columns.Bound(o => o.xyz).Width(70).Groupable(false).Title("Reply Status")
                                        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class="<#=xyx#>"});                                    
        columns.Template(t => { }).ClientTemplate(                    
                "<span class='<#=xyx#>'>some randon text</span>"                    
                );
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Telerik mvc grid columns should be bound to class properties only. You can also use dynamic model binding [here the sample](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/binding-to-a-collection-of-dynamic-objects-with-mvc3-razor.aspx)

Comment: yes thats what i am doing binding (ajax) to the class properties but i want to assign a (HTML) class name the same as the class property, `xyz` is the model property and i want to assign the same prop name as html class name ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but the approach is different depending on your binding.
I assume you are using Ajax binding, if this is the case then:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.xyz).Width(70).Groupable(false).Title("Reply Status").HtmlAttributes(new { @class="<#= xyz #>"});
```

If you are using Server binding you should use the [CellAction](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/m_telerik_web_mvc_ui_fluent_gridbuilder_1_cellaction.html) method. If you have difficulties with the latter let me know I will give you an example.

Comment: i tried that but that doesnot solve the problem it gives the class name =`"<#=xyz#>"`